# How to decide between open a dialog or pushing a new Page depending on size width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

I am working on refactoring an existing Flutter app designed for mobile to act responsive on web.

I think I fully understand MediaQuery and LayoutBuilder but I was stack with this issue about different resulting layouts that cannot be resolved inside the widget build method, or at least I don't see how to do it.
For explaining my problem lets say we have a LoginPage which has a Register button and when the button gets pressed we want to:

- Push a new Page for register on the Navigator if we are in mobile or tablet size
- Open a Dialog with the register page content if we are in desktop or web size

So this is the goal, if we are in mobile open a new page if we are in desktop open a dialog.
Sounds pretty simple if we are thinking statically, I mean if the size of the screen will not change continuoslly which is not the case. And at this point is where I am now, not sure how to resolve this when the size change after both pages are open.

Let's see some code to try to show how I was thinking this and probably you could give me some advice.
Here is a code snipped for my LoginPage where you see the void function we call when user press singin button

```
typedef VoidActionCallback = Function(BuildContext context,  RegisterResourceBloc);

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget with CoolAlertUtils {
   final VoidActionCallback onRegister;

   LoginPage({this.onRegister});

   Widget _buildSignupBtn(BuildContext context, RegisterResourceBloc resourceBloc) {
    return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
             this.onRegister(context, resourceBloc);
    },
      child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
              children: [
               TextSpan(
                text: LocaleKeys.noAccount.tr() + '? ',
                style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontSize: 18.0,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
               text: LocaleKeys.signUp.tr(),
               style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white,
                       fontSize: 18.0,
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );
    }
```

Then we have an ActionProvider that defines the actions that will occurs depending on the size:

```
class RegisterActionProvider {
   final RegisterPage registerPage;

   RegisterActionProvider({RegisterResourceBloc resourceBloc}):
      this.registerPage=RegisterPage(
                         resourceBloc: resourceBloc,
                         registerBloc: RegisterBloc(),
                        );

   registerActionMobile(BuildContext context){
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
       return this.registerPage;
      }));
   }

   registerActionWeb(BuildContext context){
    ShowDialog.show(
      context: context,
      height: 800,
      width: 600,
      child: this.registerPage);
  }
}
```

Now I have a ResponsiveAction that defines what action will be executed depending on size:

```
class ResponsiveRegisterAction{
  final List<DeviceType> breakpoints;

  ResponsiveRegisterAction({this.breakpoints});

  DeviceTypeAction buildDeviceTypeAction(RegisterResourceBloc bloc, BuildContext context){
    RegisterActionProvider provider=RegisterActionProvider(resourceBloc: bloc);
    DeviceTypeAction result=DeviceTypeAction(
      breakpoints: this.breakpoints,
      actions: [
        DeviceAction(
          name: 'MOBILE',
          builder: (context) => provider.registerActionMobile(context)
        ),
        DeviceAction(
          name: 'TABLET',
          builder: (context) => provider.registerActionMobile(context)
        ),
        DeviceAction(
          name: 'WEB',
          builder: (context) => provider.registerActionWeb(context)
        )
      ]
    );
    return result;
  }
}
```

And when the LoginPage builds it receives in its constructor the corresponding ActionProvider as we can see here in a code snipped on the routes definition of the app:

```
          routes: {
            '/': (BuildContext context) => LoadingPage(),
            '/login': (context) => ResponsiveLoginPage(loginPage: LoginPage(
                onRegister: (context, RegisterResourceBloc bloc) =>
                                ResponsiveRegisterAction(
                                  breakpoints: DeviceTypeConfig.instance.devices
                                ).buildDeviceTypeAction(bloc, context).execute(context),
              )
            ),
            '/logout': (context) => LogoutPage(),
            '/sales': (context) => SalesDashboard(),
            '/payments': (context) => PaymentsDashboard(),
            '/inventory': (context) => StockCoverageDashboard(),
            '/dashboard': (context) => MainDashboard(),
            '/aboutOf': (context) => AboutOfPage(),
            '/configuration': (context) => ConfigurationPage(),
          },
```

The magic was made inside of the execute method of the DeviceTypeAction which decides which action will execute depending on screen size.
This works fine in the sense that it acts as expected when the user clicks the signin button depending of the current screen size, but when the screen size change after the signin content was show nothing happens, and is ok, we do nothing to tacle that case.

And here we are finally arriving to the issue, how can we resolve the change of size after the register page was show?

I was exploring different alternatives but honestly I don't have a clue.
Basically because I know I can use a LayoutManager to rebuild the widget when the size change but this doesn't depends exclusively on rebuild the widget it self, it needs to change the widget tree, because for example if we are on web and we have the dialog for register open and the user resize the browser and shrink the width we need to be able to close the dialog and push a new page on the navigator instead.

So, probably there is a better way of doing this that's why I m asking.

Answer (score 1):

My way of doing this was to open a dialog on each case but reducing the padding between screen edge if it's on a small screen.
Probably not the best way but easy to implement and easy to understand and it's working ¯_(ツ)_/¯ If it's help code below using riverpod

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) {
        final isSmallScreen =
            watch(deviceType).maybeWhen(smartphone: (_) => true, orElse: () => false);
        return Opacity(
          opacity: isSmallScreen?1:0.85,
          child: AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: isSmallScreen?0:30, vertical:isSmallScreen?0: 10),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(isSmallScreen?5:20.0, 16.0, isSmallScreen?5:20.0, 20.0),
...
```

Comment: Thanks @moulte ,yes that sure it works but is not what I'm looking for, basically because we don't want to open dialogs in mobile